# FFmpeg taking too long to process video (x264)

Tags: react-native, video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-processing

I am succesfully processing my video into x264. I am happy with the output and file size I am generating, but the video seems to take as long as the video is to process.

For example, if the video is 10 seconds long, it will take 10 seconds to process the video, etc...

Even if I put `-crf 50`, it will take the same time. I find this odd behaviour.

**Note: I am using FFmpeg with FFmpegKit (React Native): https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit**

I am using full-gpl in order to be able to encode to x264. I am not sure what is wrong here or if this is normal behaviour?

Here is my FFmpeg command I am executing:

```
`-y -i ${media.path} -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune fastdecode -crf 20 -vf "crop=1350:1080, scale=960:780" -c:a copy -movflags faststart ${path}`
```

I appreciate all the help I can get here to speed this up / fix this issue.

Cheers!

Comment: Encoder is the least likely culprit. My instinct puts the blame on `scale`. BTW, "10 s for 10-s video" is a meaningless metric for outsiders who have no idea what your system configuration and input video parameters are. It wasn't that long ago encoding speed was slower than playback speed...

Comment: @kesh Thank you for the reply. It turns out removing the scale actually makes the process even longer... You are right, I will update my questions to be more specific to. my environment.

Comment: @kesh I think I figured it out. I reduced my input video format to be reduced right from the camera api (lower format directly to 1980x720), therefore there is less scaling that has to be done. Does this make sense?

Comment: yep. So, it's coming from a hi-res phone camera. If you aren't using the original resolution image for other purpose at the same time, it makes zero sense to use FFmpeg for that operation. I suspect phone has hardware built in to do the scaling far more efficiently than software-based scaling in FFmpeg.